# Cannot Center TextView Vertically using android:gravity="center_vertical" and android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Tags: xml, android-relativelayout, android, android-xml

I'm attempting to center two textviews vertically in a RelativeLayout. I'm attempting to use the paramaters `android:gravity="center_vertical"` and  `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`  however the two textviews (`uploaderTv` and `viewCountTv`) are still appearing off center (vertically)

### Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/czacA.png

### Source:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:paddingTop="7dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uploaderTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleTv"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewCountTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleTv"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/uploaderTv"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buyButton"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleTv"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:src="@drawable/buy_a_up_btn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try using android:layout_gravity instead of android:gravity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="7dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buyButton"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingTop="7dip"
            android:src="@drawable/buy_a_up_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uploaderTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewCountTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/uploaderTv"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buyButton"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This wraps the two TextViews and ImageView in a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can not center two elements vertically  in a container. The center is the middle of the container. How would you place two elements at this center?